# Changing styles at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a simple button as shown below:

```
<Button Height="20" Width="60" style="{StaticResource RedButtonStyle}"
        Click="Button_Click" />
```

Now in a ResourceDictionary I have two styles for Button:

```
<Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlueButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

Now I would like to change the button's style at runtime. So In the click event of the button I have done something like:

```
if (((Button)sender).Style == (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RedButtonStyle"])
{
    ((Button)sender).Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["BlueButtonStyle"];
}
else
{
    ((Button)sender).Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RedButtonStyle"];
}
```

Now when application starts, the background of button is Red.

```
When I click it for the first time it does not change it's colour.
When I click it for the Second time it changes it's colour to Blue.
When I click it for the Third time it changes it's colour to Red.
When I click it for the Fourth time it changes it's colour to Blue.
When I click it for the Fifth time it changes it's colour to Red.
When I click it for the Sixth time it changes it's colour to Blue.
......
.....
```

So, as defined above, the problem is : Button does not change its style when it is clicked for the first time. After that it continues to switch the style as expected.

**Update:**

In my real project I have two styles named EditButton and SaveButton as follows:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="EditButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource BrushBlueSelector}" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Turquoise" BlurRadius="8" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol" Data="M0,44.439791L18.98951,54.569246 0.47998798,62.66881z M17.428029,12.359973L36.955557,23.568769 21.957478,49.686174 20.847757,46.346189 15.11851,45.756407 14.138656,42.166935 8.5292659,41.966761 6.9493899,38.037481 2.4399572,38.477377z M26.812517,0.0009765625C27.350616,-0.012230873,27.875986,0.10826397,28.348372,0.3782568L42.175028,8.3180408C43.85462,9.2780154,44.234529,11.777948,43.02482,13.89789L41.375219,16.767812 21.460039,5.3381228 23.10964,2.4582005C23.979116,0.941679,25.437378,0.034730911,26.812517,0.0009765625z" 
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="24" Height="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushOrangeSelector}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Orange" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushHeaderBackground}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="EditButton" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="SaveButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="Border" Background="{StaticResource BrushBlueSelector}" Padding="5,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Turquoise" BlurRadius="2" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Path x:Name="buttonSymbol" Data="M8.1099597,36.94997L8.1099597,41.793968 39.213959,41.793968 39.213959,36.94997z M12.42,0.049999889L18.4,0.049999889 18.4,12.252 12.42,12.252z M0,0L7.9001866,0 7.9001866,14.64218 39.210766,14.64218 39.210766,0 47.401001,0 47.401001,47.917 0,47.917z" 
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Width="24" Height="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <TransformGroup.Children>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                </TransformGroup.Children>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Green" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushHeaderBackground}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Gray" BlurRadius="10" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="SaveButton" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />

</Style>
```

This style is applied to a button located inside a DataGridColumn. My output looks like:

Initially:

[image]

After I click the edit Button for the first time:

[image]

After I click the edit button for 2nd time:

[image]

Similarly for fourth time it changes to EditButton and for fifth time it changes to SaveButton.

Comment: @Stígandr Yes those styles exists. Those styles are declared in a ResourceDictionary and that ResourceDictionary is initiated from App.xaml file. Yes in my actual application I try to apply a template on button click event.

Comment: Sorry I read to fast, and deleted my comment. Can you check if the references are equal the first time you run?

Comment: @Stígandr How can I check the references are equal or not? Can you teach me?

Comment: @Vishal because at start it's not set directly to `Style` but to resource which points to `Style` so first time your if will be false and will set it to `RedButtonStyle` which effectively won't change it's value

Comment: @Vishal Create a breakpoint in your click method, you can check it there. You can also do a [.RefrenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) from your code/intermediate window while debugging. What I was suspecting is what dkozl said, that's your issue. Basicly you may have two Resources of the same type, but not the same refrence.

Comment: @Stígandr ReferenceEquals rturns false.

Comment: @Vishal there you have it :)

Comment: I even doubt that `Style` is initially `null`.

Comment: @Stígandr I knew that References are not equal after trying your suggestion. But what is the workaround?

Comment: @Vishal - It works for me in small sample. Can you post more details to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @RohitVats In my actual project I try to change the template of button inside style.

Comment: @RohitVats I have updated my question with the relevent information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it may be suit you:

`XAML`

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="RedButton" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="BlueButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="BlueButton" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

`Code behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    string tagValue = String.Empty;

    if (button != null)
    {
        tagValue = button.Tag.ToString();

        if (tagValue == "RedButton")
        {
            button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["BlueButtonStyle"];
        }
        else if (tagValue == "BlueButton")
        {
            button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["RedButtonStyle"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but still the problem is same.

Comment: Checking button for null after dereferencing it makes no sense.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: Please explain.

Comment: `if(button != null)` tests whether button is null or not, but in previous line `button.Tag.ToString()` would have already thrown `NullReferenceException` if button was `null`. Is that clear?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: Yes, thank you, now I understand. Do not immediately drew attention to the string `tagValue = button.Tag.ToString ()`.